# ReactJS project is not showing on localhost

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

Yesterday when I was working on my project everything was fine, but today when I start project with npm start I can see only blank screen on chrome

[image: blank screen]

[image: index.html]

[image: index.js]

[image: Network section]

Comment: check in other browser

Comment: same problem on all browsers

Comment: Any error in browser's console?  I see now that there are no errors. Can you check network section?

Comment: added screenshot in my question

Comment: This may not be a problem, but end script tab properly.

Comment: Can you try in Incognito mode in Chrome ? (meaning without any extensions, cookies, cache...)

Comment: @jare25 That was a problem :D thanks. Post as a answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you can see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)
you must properly close script tag.

Even your IDE is complaining over it, and in last screenshot you can see that something is wrong after that script tag...

Answer (score 3):

On the screenshot of the HTML in the Network tab the syntax highlighting seems to stop after the `<script...>`-Tag for apis.google.com, maybe there is something wrong with the closing of that tag? VSCode also shows the `"/>` in red.